# Binary tree - problems with insert and delete

Tags: c, algorithm, struct, tree

I need to build a binary tree using methods `inorder_tree_walk`, `tree_search`, `tree_minimum`, `tree_successor`, `tree_insert` and `tree_delete`. When I tried to compile my program I got an exception `mytree was nullptr`. I probably have problems with insert and delete methods, other part of the program works good. I wrote this code according to Cormen. I need any advices, thank's.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tree {
    int key;
    struct tree *parent, *left, *right;
    struct tree *root;
};

void inorder_tree_walk(struct tree *x) {
    if (x != NULL) {
        inorder_tree_walk(x->left);
        printf("%d ", x->key);
        inorder_tree_walk(x->right);
    }
}

struct tree *tree_search(struct tree *x, int key) {
    if (x == NULL || key == x->key)
        return x;
    if (key < (x->key)) {
        return tree_search(x->left, key);
    } else {
        return tree_search(x->right, key);
    }
}

struct tree *tree_minimum(struct tree *x) {
    while (x->left != NULL)
        x = x->left;
    return x;
}

struct tree *tree_successor(struct tree *x) {
    struct tree *y;
    if (x->right != NULL) {
        return tree_minimum(x->right);
    }
    y = x->parent;

    while (y != NULL && x == y->right) {
        x = y;
        y = y->parent;
        return y;
    }
}

struct tree *tree_insert(struct tree *mytree, int key) {
    struct tree *x = NULL;
    struct tree *z = NULL;
    struct tree *y = NULL;

    x = mytree->root;
    while (x != NULL) {
        y = x;
        if (z->key < x->key)
            x = x->left;
        else
            x = x->right;
    }
    z->parent = y;

    if (y == NULL) {
        mytree->root = z;
    } else
    if (z->key < y->key)
        y->left = z;
    else
        y->right = z;
    return 0;
}

struct tree *tree_delete(struct tree *tree, int key) {
    struct tree *z = NULL;
    struct tree *x;
    struct tree *y;

    if (z->left == NULL || z->right == NULL) {
        y = z;
    } else
        y = tree_successor(z);

    if (y->left != NULL)
        x = y->left;
    else 
        x = y->right;

    if (x != NULL)
        x->parent = y->parent;

    if (y->parent = NULL)
        tree->root = x;
    else
    if (y = y->parent->left)
        y->parent->left = x;
    else
        y->parent->right = x;

    if (y != z)
        z->key = y->key;

    return y;
}

int main() {
    tree *root = NULL;
    root = tree_insert(root, 7);
    root = tree_insert(root, 13);
    root = tree_insert(root, 8);
    root = tree_insert(root, 23);
    root = tree_insert(root, -7);
    root = tree_insert(root, 13);
    root = tree_insert(root, 31);
    root = tree_insert(root, 5);
    inorder_tree_walk(root);
    printf("\n\n");

    tree *tmp;
    tmp = tree_minimum(root);
    printf("minimum = %d\n", tmp->key);

    root = tree_delete(root, 8);
    root = tree_delete(root, -7);
    root = tree_delete(root, 31);
    inorder_tree_walk(root);
    printf("\n\n");

    tmp = tree_search(root, 13);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("not found\n");
    } else {
        printf("found\n");
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: At which location in your code do you get the exception, when running the program?

Comment: I don't know if my eyes are deceiving me, but how are you able to build a tree dynamically without a single call to `new`, `malloc`, etc.?  From what I see, all the pointers you're using are uninitialized and none of this code should work.  It's as if you missed the entire chapter on dynamic allocation.  Also, pick a language, `C` or `C++` -- they are not the same.

Comment: During the first call of `tree_insert()`, the pointer `root = NULL;` and the `x = mytree->root;` generates the Exception. And, the only value returned from that function is `return 0;` at the end.

Comment: "Introduction to Algorithms" by Thomas Cormen is a fine book.  It is not a programming book.  If you want to learn C or C++ (pick one) get a good programming book on the language.  After that, learn how to implement algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem in the `while` loop of function `tree_successor()`.  You should take the `return` out of the while block:

```
struct tree *tree_successor(struct tree *x) {
    struct tree *y;
    if (x->right != NULL) {
        return tree_minimum(x->right);
    }
    y = x->parent;

    while (y != NULL && x == y->right) {
        x = y;
        y = y->parent;
    }
    return y;
}
```

`tree_insert` invokes undefined behavior because `z` is `NULL` when it is dereferenced in the first loop. `z` should be initialized with a newly allocated node with the proper key value.

`tree_delete` has even more problems, you do not walk the tree from the root node at all.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you should remove the data member `root` from the structure definition.

```
struct tree {
    int key;
    struct tree *parent, *left, *right;
    struct tree *root;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

It does not make sense to have such a data member.

So the structure can look like

```
struct tree {
    int key;
    struct tree *parent, *left, *right;
};
```

The function `tree_insert` is wrong. At least it has to return a pointer to the root node of the tree while it returns 0.

```
struct tree *tree_insert(struct tree *mytree, int key) {
    //...
    return 0;
    ^^^^^^^^
}
```

Also the parameter `mytree` can be equal to NULL but you are ignoring this case.

I would write the function the following way

```
struct tree * tree_insert(struct tree *root, int key)
{
    struct tree *parent = NULL;
    struct tree **current = &root;

    while (*current  != NULL)
    {
        parent = *current;

        if (key < ( *current )->key)
        {
            current = &( *current )->left;
        }
        else
        {
            current = &(*current)->right;
        }
    }

    *current = (struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));

    (*current)->key = key;
    (*current)->parent = parent;
    (*current)->left = NULL;
    (*current)->right = NULL;

    return root;
}
```

Using this function you can at last add nodes to the tree and output the tree.:)

There are other errors in your implementation of the tree. But the ability to add new nodes will simplify you to debug your code.:)

Here is a test program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct tree * tree_insert(struct tree *root, int key)
{
    struct tree *parent = NULL;
    struct tree **current = &root;

    while (*current  != NULL)
    {
        parent = *current;

        if (key < ( *current )->key)
        {
            current = &( *current )->left;
        }
        else
        {
            current = &(*current)->right;
        }
    }

    *current = (struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));

    (*current)->key = key;
    (*current)->parent = parent;
    (*current)->left = NULL;
    (*current)->right = NULL;

    return root;
}

void inorder_tree_walk( const struct tree *root ) 
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        inorder_tree_walk(root->left);
        printf("%d ", root->key);
        inorder_tree_walk(root->right);
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    tree *root = NULL;

    root = tree_insert(root, 7);
    root = tree_insert(root, 13);
    root = tree_insert(root, 8);
    root = tree_insert(root, 23);
    root = tree_insert(root, -7);
    root = tree_insert(root, 13);
    root = tree_insert(root, 31);
    root = tree_insert(root, 5);
    inorder_tree_walk(root);

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

The program output is

```
-7 5 7 8 13 13 23 31
```

It corresponds to the following tree

```
     7
    /\
   /  \
  /    \
-7      13
 \     / \
  \   /   \
   6 8     23
          / \
         /   \
       13     31
```